# Visual Basic percentage data saving failure

Tags: vba, save, percentage

I have a problem with saving % data to database. I have a template, and if the % more, than 100%, the program Can't save the data properly. Could you explain me, why is that and what I have to do, to eliminate this problem?

Here is my code:

```
    Sub xhusarany()

Dim xhusarany As String
Dim v As Integer
Dim cella As String

xhusarany = Sheets("gyártott termék").Range("n44").Value
cella = "ak" & adatsorszam
Sheets("adatbázis").Range(cella).Value = xhusarany

Call xhusaranyspec

End Sub
```

And here is a screenshot from my database with wrong saved data:

[image]

Thank you in advance!

Comment: What do you mean with *cannot save properly*? What happens if you save such a workbook?

Comment: Please create a [reprex]. In your current snippet, `adatsorszam` is not defined, and it's impossible to tell what `xhusaranyspec` does.

Comment: Thank you for your reply and sorry, if I missed some necessary information. In the meantime, we came up with a solution for our problem, so this question is irrelevant now.